# Functional Equation's final step

Tags: functions, polynomials, functional-equations

I am pretty close on solving a functional equation but i am stuck on 
$f(f(x
+2017)-f(x+1))=constant$ ,for all real x.
Should I be able to get something out of it or should I change direction? I am stuck for hours.
Post note: the constant is non-zero and $f(0)=0$

Comment: Do you know anything else about the equation?

Comment: I could add the original question , but my question is if i can find anything important from this particular relation,which to me seems promising.

Answer (score 1):

There are linear solutions to this where $f(x) = mx +b $. Given that we know $f(0) = 0$ then $f(x) = mx$.

Taking $f(f(x+2017) - f(x+1)) = k$ we can substitute $$\begin{align}f(m(x+2017) - m(x +1)) &= k \\
f(mx+2017m - mx -m) &= \\
f(2016m) &= \\
2016m^2 &= \\
m &= \pm \sqrt{\frac{k}{2016}}
\end{align}$$